# Keyboard shortcut to insert into cell in MS Excel (2008) on a Mac?

Tags: mac, microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

Keyboard shortcut to insert into cell in MS Excel (2008) on a Mac?

In Windows, `F2` will put the cursor at the end of a cell's text.  What's the keyboard shortcut to do this on a Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

---

In Mac, <kbd>F2</kbd> is assigned to cut the contents of the current cell.

[With a bit of help from a third-party program, you can make F2 to edit the current cell in Excel (2004 or 2008) on the Mac.](http://www.macworld.com/article/134549/2008/07/exceleditcell.html)